# arc strong properties and memory management

Tags: automatic-ref-counting

let's say we have a controller A and it has two strong properties B and C.
B and C have one common type of property D.Releationship is as follows:
[image]

If I remove the bond betwwen A and C by setting the property C in A to nil, would C be released or it keeps existing until the bond between A and B or B and D is removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C will be removed, assuming D has no strong reference to C. Since there are no remaining strong references, it is deallocated.

Your diagram represents these relationships as two-way bonds, but remember that a property is only a one-way relationship; just because C has a D pointer doesn't mean D knows anything about C.